# List files recursively within directories that start with a specified letter

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to get all `*.html` files within certain directories via PowerShell. 
Folder structure looks like this:

```
folder
  subfolder1
  subfolder2
  subfolder3
  subfolder4
  ...
```

Subfolders are in alphabetical order. There exist folders from a to z. I now want to get all `.html` files within the folders that start with the letter b.

I tried

```
Get-ChildItem -Path *.html -Recurse -Force
```

this gives me all `html` files from all folders. But how can I restrict the path, so that it only checks subdirectories that start with b?

Comment: `*.html` -> `b*.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient, but you could do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory b* | Select -ExpandProperty FullName | % {Get-ChildItem $_\*.html}
```

Or depending on what you want, you could do `Get-ChildItem -Directory b* -Recurse` as well.

You might need to format `Get-ChildItem $_` depending on what you want output to look like, since it writes the directory by default.

Comment: `(Get-ChildItem -Directory b*).fullname | % {Get-ChildItem $_\*.html}`  will perform much faster... and to recurse `(Get-ChildItem -Directory b*).fullname | % {Get-ChildItem $_ -recurse *.html}`   THE simplest I found was `get-childitem b* -recurse *.html` which could be put in parenthesis with .fullname if that's your desire

Comment: For me I did measure-command and they performed almost identically on a large tree.

Comment: logically it will perform faster, but after thinking about it, since the chunk of processing is the first get-child item, which is reliant on disk speed, you may have a very valid point. anyhow, whats weird is the last command I posted is about half the speed, even though there are no pipes. Also measure-command isn't reliable on 1 loop, it's best to do something like `$measure = measure-command{1..100|foreach{command to test}}; $measure.milliseconds / 100`